# VSTS LoadTest, connection string and TFS2010

Tags: connection-string, load-testing

We have a couple of loadtests running on a build server and I've been having problems with persisting the results from the test in a resultstore database. It works fine when running locally and up and until a week ago, the test result got persisted when running on the build server (TFS2010). Note I have no test controller or test agents. Only a build controller and build agents. I've setup the connection string for the controller 'Local - No controller' and it is seemed to be saved correctly (can see the connection string on the build server too). But when running via the build server, the result is not saved in the database. Locally works fine. So what am I doing wrong here and where is the connection string saved? My guess is that it follows the test controller and hence I do not explicit have one, my guess is that it uses a default local test controller. Any thoughts on where the chain breaks?

Comment: Can nobody explain how the connection string is configured/persisted, when using a local controller on the build server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fixed the problem, by opening visual studio on each of the build servers and configuring the connection string - *sigh